# typeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement context menu using polymer paper menu. Whenever I remove node from dom. `polymer` is throwing error like this

> typeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

and I get the following error message:

[image: Error screenshot attached]

What shall I do?

Comment: Please update the question to include the relevant source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue. This is due to polymer-mini.html checks if the arg passed to document.documentElement.contains(**node**) is node type. Debugging i could see that an event propagated so the last iteration was window object causing this issue.
My solution was adding ev.stopPropagation() to the code before removing action.