# Python Selenium: Send_keys Failed to execute

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys, traceback

I'd like to fill out a form with

```
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("Test")
```

But I get this error everytime I run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fill.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("Test")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 351, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.117)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)
```

```html
<input first_and_last="true" placeholder="name" class="string required" type="text" name="flname" id="name">
```

Note: I also get an error for searching for the name. If I search for Xpath it fills out the form very slow and I need it to be faster.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the HTML snippet?

Comment: How did that **`f`** got included in the trace logs as in `find_element_by_id("ƒname")` where as your code reads as `find_element_by_id("name")`

Comment: Added HTML snippet!
The "f" was a paste failure, removed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of the *locator Strategies* :

- **css_selector** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.string.required#name").send_keys("Test")
  ```
- **xpath** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='string required' and @id='name']").send_keys("Test")
  ```

---

### Update

I have tried to lookout for a solution to both of the error messages you were facing and here are the relevant details :

- `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` : As per the discussion [typeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542901/typeerror-failed-to-execute-contains-on-node-parameter-1-is-not-of-type-n?rq=1) possibly your application is based on **Polymer** and before you start looking out for any element soon after *Page Load* as a precautionary measure induce a waiter through [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) along with proper [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)
- `Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."` : As per the discussion [JS: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter is not of type 'Element'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196991/js-failed-to-execute-getcomputedstyle-on-window-parameter-is-not-of-type) and [Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279967/failed-to-execute-getcomputedstyle-on-window-parameter-1-is-not-of-type-el) points to the similar behavior that the desired element is not actually present within the DOM while a *JavaScript* or an *Ajax Call* is working towards adding/removing elements.

Comment: "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'." on CSS

Comment: @Julian Checkout my answer update and let me know if any questions.